# Get data type byte size

Tags: java, byte

Is it possible to get byte size for data type? I found this: java.lang.Float.SIZE, but it returns 32. I have this code:

```
   ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4)
```

I want to rewrite it like this:

```
    ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * FLOAT_BYTE_SIZE_CONSTANT)
```

why is the java.lang.Float.SIZE returning 32? because it's signed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found this: java.lang.Float.SIZE, but it returns 32

Yes, thats true, read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html):

> static int    SIZE
>   The number of bits used to represent a float value.

What you are searching for is `Float.BYTES`:

> static int    BYTES
>   The number of bytes used to represent a float value.

If you aren't using Java8 already (I would recommend using Java8), you just need to divide `SIZE` with 8 to get the result you want to get.

Comment: That's new in Java 8. Dividing SIZE by 8 shouldn't be too much of a hassle on previous releases.

Comment: @Mat Thanks, didn't know it wasn't available before Java8. Added this into my answer